# What should i use to compare the first two input strings on my password app

Tags: java

1. I would like to add in the very beginning that if the passwords don't match start over...but every time I try to do it I mess up the whole thing
2. The password has to be 8 characters long, one capital letter and one number
3. Some issues I encounter is that if the first pass is not valid it still will ask for a second confirmation password, why move on when the first one is invalid 4.i was thinking maybe a compareTo() method or compareChar since it can be numbers, .equals? I am open to any other suggestions and tips to optimize performance I know my code is sloppy

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Please enter password : ");
       String password = in.nextLine();

   ```
   System.out.print("Please re-enter the password to confirm : ");
   String confirm = in.nextLine();

   boolean condition;
   condition = isValid(password);
   while (!password.equals(confirm) || (!condition)) {
       System.out.println("The password is invalid");

       System.out.print("Please enter the password again : ");
       password = in.nextLine();
       System.out.println(PassCheck(password));
       System.out.print("Please re-enter the password to confirm : ");
       confirm = in.nextLine();
       System.out.println(PassCheck(password));
       condition = isValid(password);

   }
   if (isValid(password)) {
       System.out.println("The password is valid");

   }
   ```

   }

   public static boolean isValid(String password) {
       Boolean atleastOneUpper = false;
       Boolean atleastOneLower = false;
       Boolean atleastOneDigit = false;
       if (password.length() < 8) { // If its less then 8 characters, its automatically not valid
           return false;
       }

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) { // Lets iterate over only once. Saving time
       if (Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i))) {
           atleastOneUpper = true;
       } else if (Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(i))) {
           atleastOneLower = true;
       } else if (Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i))) {
           atleastOneDigit = true;
       }
   }

   return (atleastOneUpper && atleastOneLower && atleastOneDigit); // Return true IFF the password is atleast eight characters long, has atleast one upper, lower and digit
   ```

   }

   public static String PassCheck(String Password) {

   ```
   String result = "Valid Password";           // Sets  valid
   int length = 0;                     // Stores the #
   int numCount = 0;                   // store numbers in the password
   int capCount = 0;                                       // Variable used to store capital letters in the password


   for (int x = 0; x < Password.length(); x++) {
       if ((Password.charAt(x) >= 47 && Password.charAt(x) <= 58) || (Password.charAt(x) >= 64 && Password.charAt(x) <= 91)
               || (Password.charAt(x) >= 97 && Password.charAt(x) <= 122)) {

       } else {
           result = "Password Contains Invalid Character!";//Checks that password contains only letters and numbers
       }

       if ((Password.charAt(x) > 47 && Password.charAt(x) < 58)) { // Counts the number of numbers
           numCount++;
       }

       if ((Password.charAt(x) > 64 && Password.charAt(x) < 91)) { // Counts the number of capital letters
           capCount++;
       }

       length = (x + 1);                   // check passwords length

   } // Ends the for loop

   if (numCount < 1) {                     // Checks numbers
       result = "Not Enough Numbers in Password!";
   }

   if (capCount < 1) {             // Checks that Capital letters
       result = "You need atleast least Capital letter!";
   }

   if (length < 7) {               // Checks length
       result = "Password needs to be 7 characters long";
   }
   return (result);}}
   ```

Comment: or not really strings.....input...could be letters or @#@#4%#

Comment: probably have a few useless things in there...be nice im a noob

Comment: 1. what went wrong ? 2. what went wrong ? 3. just add `if(isValid(password))` and ask for confirm input there 4. Even if there are numbers in the password, `String.equals()` is the best option. 5. I don't think performance is important in such program compared to readability.

Comment: Code that uses numeric ASCII codes representing characters is not readable. Use the actual characters instead. E.g. `password.charAt(n) >= 'A'`. The char type is an integral type which can be compared just like any other integer.

Answer (score 0):

You basically can achieve what you want by slightly modifying the logic that you already have. Without any major refactoring to your code you can do the following:

```
String password = "";    
System.out.print("Please enter password : ");
while(!isValid(password)) {                     
    password = in.nextLine();
    if(!isValid(password)) {
        System.out.println(PassCheck(password));
        System.out.print("Password is not valid, try again : ");
    }
}
```

Sample output with the desired result:

```
Please enter password : test
Password is not valid, try again : test2
Password is not valid, try again : Test1test
Please re-enter the password to confirm : Test1test
The password is valid
```

Full code:

```
public class Password {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String password = "";    
        System.out.print("Please enter password : ");
        while(!isValid(password)) {                     
            password = in.nextLine();
            if(!isValid(password)) {
                System.out.println(PassCheck(password));
                System.out.print("Password is not valid, try again : ");
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Please re-enter the password to confirm : ");
        String confirm = in.nextLine();

        boolean condition;
        condition = isValid(password);
        while (!password.equals(confirm) || (!condition)) {
            System.out.println("The password is invalid");

            System.out.print("Please enter the password again : ");
            password = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(PassCheck(password));
            System.out.print("Please re-enter the password to confirm : ");
            confirm = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(PassCheck(password));
            condition = isValid(password);

        }
        if (isValid(password)) {
            System.out.println("The password is valid");

        }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(String password) {
        Boolean atleastOneUpper = false;
        Boolean atleastOneLower = false;
        Boolean atleastOneDigit = false;
        if (password.length() < 8) { // If its less then 8 characters, its automatically not valid
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) { // Lets iterate over only once. Saving time
            if (Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i))) {
                atleastOneUpper = true;
            } else if (Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(i))) {
                atleastOneLower = true;
            } else if (Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i))) {
                atleastOneDigit = true;
            }
        }

        return (atleastOneUpper && atleastOneLower && atleastOneDigit); // Return true IFF the password is atleast eight characters long, has atleast one upper, lower and digit
    }

    public static String PassCheck(String Password) {

        String result = "Valid Password";           // Sets  valid
        int length = 0;                     // Stores the #
        int numCount = 0;                   // store numbers in the password
        int capCount = 0;                                       // Variable used to store capital letters in the password


        for (int x = 0; x < Password.length(); x++) {
            if ((Password.charAt(x) >= 47 && Password.charAt(x) <= 58) || (Password.charAt(x) >= 64 && Password.charAt(x) <= 91)
                    || (Password.charAt(x) >= 97 && Password.charAt(x) <= 122)) {

            } else {
                result = "Password Contains Invalid Character!";//Checks that password contains only letters and numbers
            }

            if ((Password.charAt(x) > 47 && Password.charAt(x) < 58)) { // Counts the number of numbers
                numCount++;
            }

            if ((Password.charAt(x) > 64 && Password.charAt(x) < 91)) { // Counts the number of capital letters
                capCount++;
            }

            length = (x + 1);                   // check passwords length

        } // Ends the for loop

        if (numCount < 1) {                     // Checks numbers
            result = "Not Enough Numbers in Password!";
        }

        if (capCount < 1) {             // Checks that Capital letters
            result = "You need atleast least Capital letter!";
        }

        if (length < 7) {               // Checks length
            result = "Password needs to be 7 characters long";
        }

        return (result);
    }
}
```

So all I did was add a loop to only continue, past the first password, when the inputted password conforms to the isValid() conditions. Otherwise it prompts the user that the password is not valid and to try again.

Comment: Thanks and if i add the passCheck method it will tell the user why.

Comment: True, I just initially skimmed your code. For completeness I added your passCheck() suggestion to the solution.